# Why unused default export error in React Native Expo project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

After installing React Navigation and command expo start:
1.) Simulators have blank white screens
2.) Web port has a blank white screen
3.) App.js now has unused default export

Troubleshooting:
1.) Uninstalled all React Navigation dependancies
2.) Reinstalled all React Navigation dependancies

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import StackNavigator from './Components/StackNavigator';

export default function App() {

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <StackNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

**StackNavigator.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import ResumeScreen from './ResumeScreen';

const StackNavigator = () => {

    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Resume"
                    component={ResumeScreen}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
};

export default StackNavigator;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "expo": "~47.0.8",
    "expo-device": "~5.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine multiple forms of navigation incorrectly. Try just sticking with Drawer Navigation. Below is a simple working example.

### App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ResumeScreen from "./screens/ResumeScreen";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Resume" component={ResumeScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

### package.json

```js
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

### screens/HomeScreen.js

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

### screens/ResumeScreen.js

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const ResumeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>ResumeScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ResumeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```